# No suitable encoder found (java websocket)

Tags: javascript, java, web-services, websocket

I have some problem I tried to write some webapplication with websockets for data streaming it's not ready yet but I'm working on it.
I try to send my server a String and the server should send me the message back with an UUID I first just sended the UUID with

```
session.getBasicRemote().sendText(uuid.tostring())
```

that worked well but now I try to send a map so I can send the UUID  and the String together by using

`session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(map);`

but now my JS client don't reciev the data I try to send my server throws the exception

> javax.websocket.EncodeException: No suitable encoder found

I don't know now how to solve this problem.

JS code

```
var websocket;
$(document).ready(function(){
    websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/TimeStreamingTestartID-1.0-SNAPSHOT/websockets/simplestockmarket")

    websocket.onopen = function(){ 
    alert("SUCESS: REGISTERED!!");
    }

$("#tblcontainer").html('<table id="tableID" class="table table-bordered" ><thead><tr><th>Identification</th><th>Text</th></tr></thead></table>')
$("#start").click(function(){

    websocket.send("Test")
    websocket.onmessage = function(erg){ 
    $("#tableID").append('<tr><td>'+"1"+'</td><td>'+erg+'</td></tr>')
    console.log(erg);
    }

});
});
```

My java onMessage method

```
    @OnMessage
public void message(Session session,String message) throws IOException {
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    Map map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(uuid,message);

    try {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(map);
    } catch (EncodeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does your server endpoint look like? Do you have this annotation on top of it?

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/whatever", encoders = {MessageEncoder.class}, decoders = {MessageDecoder.class}) 
public class MessageService {

    @OnMessage
    public void message()...
}
```

Comment: `@ServerEndpoint("/websockets/simplestockmarket")
public class SimpleStockMarketWSServerEndpoint `

looks like this at the moment tried to write like you but there is no MessageEncoder

Comment: Well, if you don't have it import the jar.

Comment: if you would tell me the name of the jar that would be nice too :D

Comment: Pardon me, you have to write your own: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/12/websocket-multiple-users-encoders-decoders-dogs/

Comment: Thanks :D I'll try this hope my skills are enougth to write this lol